# Is the set of all non-intersecting points an open set of the standard topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

I'm wondering if the set of all non-intersecting points on the plane $P=\mathbb{R}^2$ is an open set of the standard topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

To make this precise, suppose $X=(P,X)$ is the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and that $d$ is the euclidean metric on $X$. Let $\{x,y\}\in X$ be a pair of points in the plane.
We define the closed set $\overline{xy}\in X$ as:
$$\overline{xy}=\{p\in X|d(x,p)+d(p,y)=d(x,y)\}$$
This is, $\overline{xy}$ is the unique set containing all points in the line segment joining $x$ and $y$. Let $o\notin\overline{xy}$ be a point in $X$. We define the set of all non-intersecting points, $S_o\subseteq X$ as:
$$S_o=\{p\in X|\overline{xy}\cap\overline{op}=\emptyset\}$$
Where $\overline{op}$ is the unique set containing all points in the line segment joining $o$ and $p$. This is, $S_o$ contains all points $p$ such that the line segment $\overline{op}$ does not intersect $\overline{xy}$, for an arbitrary $o\in X$.

Given this, how can we prove that $S_o\in X$ is an open set of $X$?

Comment: Your notation is very confused.

Comment: I fell into the recursion $X= (P,X)$ and may never exit.

Comment: $S_o$ *can* be an open set. Your example with d(x,y) going to infinity is equivalent to the intersection, if you like, of all open sets $S_o$ associated with x and y pertaining to a single line. Infinite intersections of open sets can be closed; there is no problem with that.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes... I was actually unsure about that one, but it isn't the first time i see a topologic space defined like that. I'm kind'a self-taught math-learner. I'm open to notation suggestions, if you would care to provide them.

Comment: In your edit, you seem to mix up line segments and lines. E.g. if we use as our "line to avoid" the $x$-axis, and take $o=(0,1)$, then the resulting $S_o$ is not the horizontal line through $o$ but rather the entire upper half plane, which is open.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, you're right. I implicitly assumed that $d(x,y)=d(o,p)=\infty_+$. I'll just delete that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking whether, given $o, x, y \in \Bbb{R}^2$, where $o \not\in \overline{xy}$, is the set $S = \{p \in \Bbb{R}^2 \mid \overline{xy} \cap \overline{op} = \emptyset\}$ open. The answer is yes. To see this, we can assume w.l.o.g. that $o = 0$. Then $S = A \cup B$, where $A$ is the interior of the triangle $\triangle{0xy}$ and $B$ is the complement of the cone formed by the rays $0x\infty$ and $0y\infty$ that do pass through $\overline{xy}$. $A$ and $B$ are both open, and hence so is $S$.

Comment: Nice answer, I find this really interesting, the operation that assigns to each line segment and point the region that would be "lit up" by a light at that point, minding the line segment as an obstruction, behaves almost like the compliment in that an open segment creates a closed region, and a closed region creates an open region

Comment: Moreover, if you take the union of such regions for all points, you retrieve the normal compliment I believe

Comment: Yes, the union of the open regions $S_o$ for all $o \not\in \overline{xy}$ does indeed comprise the complement of $\overline{xy}$: it is clearly contained in the complement because $\overline{xy} \cap S_o= \emptyset$, and the compliment contains it because for any $z \not\in \overline{xy}$, $z \in S_z$. I don't think a closed segment creates a closed region under this construction.

Comment: I am assuming your last statement was meant to be "...an open segment creates a closed segment..." and if so, I agree, but I believe i n $\mathbb{R}^n$ that an open all creates a closed set

Comment: Apologies, I meant what you said and not what I typed, but you won't get a closed set from an open segment. E.g., assume $o$, $x$ and $y$ are not collinear, let $p = (x + y)/2$ (the midpoint of $\overline{xy}$) and consider a sequence of points $p_i$ in the interior of the segment $\overline{op}$ that converge to $p$. The $p_i$ are all in the analogue of the OP's $S_o$, but they converge to $p$, which is not.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I mistakenly thought so at first, but I forgot that even an open segment contains most of its boundary, however, I think an open ball produces a closed set

Comment: @Carlyle: you are right about an open ball producing a closed set, even in the corner case where $o$ is on the boundary of the open ball (when the result your get is a closed half-space).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
the distance between two compact disjoint subsets, (e.g. - two closed and bounded disjoint intervals) of the Euclidean plane is positive.

> Added Later:

Let $p$ be a point in the set $S_o$.
The intervals $\overline{op},\overline{xy}$ both being compact, the distance between them is positive, say, $\delta>0$. Given any point $q$, the maximal distance between the intervals $\overline{op}$ and $\overline{oq}$ is $d(p,q)$. Assume $d(p,q)<\delta$,if $w\in\overline{xy}\cap\overline{oq}$, then $d(w,p)\leq d(p,q)<\delta$, contradicting the assumption that the distance between $\overline{xy}$ and $\overline{op}$ is precisely $\delta$. Hence the intersection $\overline{xy}\cap\overline{oq}$ must be empty. Since this holds for every $q\in B(p,\delta)$, this proves that $S_o$ is open.