# Does the relative complement behave like the complement?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

In the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4834179/is-the-set-of-all-non-intersecting-points-an-open-set-of-the-standard-topology-i) question, it is shown that the *relative complement* (defined below) of a closed line-segment is an open set. Similarly, it can be shown that the relative complement of an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a closed set. This suggests that the relative complement bears some similarities to the regular complement.

> **Definition 1**: Given a metric space $(X,d)$, and two points $x,y\in X$, the line segment $\overline{xy}$ is the set of points *between* $x$ and $y$, we say a point $z$ is between $x,y$ if $d(x,y) = d(x,z)+d(z,y)$.

> **Definition 2**:Given a metric space $(X,d)$, a subset $S\subseteq X$, and a point $x\in X$, the relative complement of $S$ with respect to $x$, denoted by $C_{x}(S)$ is the set $$\{y\in X\mid\overline{xy} \cap S=\emptyset\}$$

Clearly, $C_x(S)\subseteq S^c$, the normal complement. I have 2 basic questions about this new concept:

1. Is the relative complement of an arbitrary open/closed set a closed/open set?
2. Is there an infinite metric space with a *very bright point*, $x$ such that for any subset $S$ not containing $x$,  $C_x(S)= S^c$ ?

(The point is called "very bright" because rays emanating from it are able to reach anywhere)

**Answer to the second question** The discrete metric on $\mathbb{N}$ is an example of such a space, since here we have $\overline{nm} = \{n,m\}$, so the points in $C_0(S)$ are precisely those not in $S$ (provided $0\notin S$)

Comment: A "compliment" is "a polite expression of praise or admiration".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin apologies, I thought I had caught and changed all instances of this typo, but see now that one  had slipped me by. Thank you correcting it